# Google Sheets : How to convert cell address to text/string?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to change the cell address to string/text. For example :

```
AB123 --> "AB123"
```

I want to use it with indirect(), for example to refer to **A1:A100** where the **'100'** is fetched from cell X1 -->

```
indirect( to_string(  A1 ) & ":A" & X1  )
```

I didn't do **indirect("A1:A"&X1)** because since "A1" is static string so when i insert a new row on the very top so to shift down row 1,  then the formula won't update automatically and will still refer to A1:A100 , in fact it should now refer to A2:A100 after the row insert. In this case i want to keep the A1 not as string so after insert it should updated to A2

What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: Where is the address coming from or what means are you inputting it into the desired function? I ask because the address as written is already a string... Usually, it's the other way around - you want to input a string and turn it into a cell or range address. If you have an address already, then it must be the output of something... What's that something?

Comment: The reason you've not found a simple way to do it is that it's not a useful or necessary thing to do in Sheets usually.  If you're at a place where you want it, there's likely a better way to do whatever it is that you're doing.

Comment: @MattKing Sorry i didn't explain the detail. I have modified my question above. Pls have a look for the reason. So definitely there's a use of it.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, i've updated my post with further detail. Thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
=cell("address", AB123)
```

[image]

Comment: YES, This is Perfect ! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This (or something like it) might also work instead of all that "indirect" stuff.

OFFSET is very good at defining changing ranges like that.

```
=OFFSET(A2,,,X1,1)
```

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(123, COLUMN(AB1)))
```

or:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(123, 28))
```

to get range `AB123`